# Find numerical patterns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find rows in pandas df which correspond to a particular pattern. For example:

```
df = 

 q1  q2  q3  q4  q5
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0
1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0
3.0 1.0 1.0 7.0 1.0
```

is there something like:

```
>> df == [1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0] 
>> False
   False
   True
   False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want compare `numpy array` with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) or 
[`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df ==np.array([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0]))
      q1    q2     q3     q4     q5
0   True  True  False   True   True
1   True  True  False   True  False
2   True  True   True   True   True
3  False  True  False  False   True

mask = (df == np.array([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0])).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Or:

```
mask = ~(df != np.array([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0])).any(axis=1)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: just a quick question: how to find all unique rows?

Comment: use `df = df.drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use df.values to compare with the list and check if all elements of row equals the list.

```
(df.values==[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0]).all(axis=1)
Out[334]: array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```